# Опять вопрос о лицензиях GNU, BSD и прочая связанная с этим ситуация

Tags: лицензирование, gnu

Работаю над своим продуктом вида CMS который активно использую в своих работах. По ходу дела набираюсь опыта, и созрел для начала разработки новой ветки 2.0 в которой собираюсь, учитывая приобретенный опыт, внести ряд улучшений как на уровне ядра, так и на уровне создания модулей для своей системы. Все это планирую выпустить в мир под лицензией BSD. А теперь, внимание вопрос :).

Понятное дело что я сам все не осилю. Использовать сторонние разработки считаю абсолютно нормальным, и оправданным. И поскольку любая CMS это в первую очередь огромная работа над системой управления, то мне очень и очень нужен пользовательский интерфейс. До не давнего времени, вопрос о выборе фреймворка не стоял вообще. То есть, это однозначно была Jquery UI. Хорошая библиотека, но много чего в ней мне не нравится, и особенно реально заметно ее вес. Она тяжелая как не крути, да и багов к сожалению предостаточно ....

Мое внимание привернула [альтернатива](http://www.kendoui.com/) . Уверен те, кто еще не знаком с этим проектом будут под впечатлением.

Что мне тут понравилось.
 1. Гораздо меньше талмутов в виде CSS файлов.
 2. Очень аккуратно оформлен весь исходный код. Разобраться более чем реально.
 3. Ряд очень интересных виджетов, аналогов которым нет. Особенно понравился  виджет позволяющий организовывать вывод списков в виде таблиц, и управление  ними. Сортировка, выделение поля, строки, листалка. Все в одном.
 4. В исходниках нашел пару графических изображений которые говорят о том, что скорее всего в этом фреймворке появится еще и свой WYSIWYG. Ну в любом случае следы его возможного появления достаточно хорошо заметны :).
 5. Что тоже не мало важно. Это все тщательно тестируется под мобильными устройствами. А эта эра не за горами.
 6. Все спроектировано с учетом многоязычности, и региональных особенностей.

Я не хочу перечислять все что мне понравилсь, каждый пусть сделает выводы сам. Но настроение мне испортила их лицензия, в которой четко сказано что это платный продукт. Тем не менее, я решил все-таки написать письмо авторам, и вот тут, мое настроение поднялось опять.

На вопрос что нужно для того чтобы вашу разработку можно было встроить в свою CMS я получил очень неожиданный ответ, и информации об этом на офф сайте я не находил.

> product of yours (either public site
>   or end-user product), you will need to
>   buy the commercial license for it. In
>   case your CMS is under OS license
>   (GPLv3 or compatible), you should be
>   able to use the Open Source version of
>   Kendo UI, once available.
>
> The pricing options for the Kendo UI
>   suite are not finalized yet. They will
>   be announced with the official v1 of
>   the product, down for November.
>
> What I can say for now is that the
>   current internal discussions revolve
>   around $500 price tag for the Kendo UI
>   bundle.

Забавно правда? Я попытался перезвонить нескольким юристам, уточнить детали. Но можете не поверить, но никто из них даже не знает что такое GNU, BSD. Посему, надежда только на то, что кто-то с этим сталкивался. Волнует вопрос, что если мой проект бесплатный, а кто-то захочет на его основе сделать коммерческий проект, то не повлечет ли это за собой потребность покупать лицензию от Kendo? Или возможно еще какие-то нюансы, о которых хотелось бы выяснить пока не поздно.

Comment: столько текста, жаль я не юрист =)

Answer (score 1):

[Условия лицензии GNU GPL доступным языком](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/patent/131397/) 
[Мир лицензий: разбираемся с GNU GPL](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/Dura_Lex/45808/)

Comment: Я все это читал но всеравно спасибо. Основной вопрос сстоит в том что если система бесплатная а в ее составе есть модуль который бесплатный с условием что проект не коммерческий.

Comment: В приведенном вами отрывке, написано что они еще не определились со стоимостью. Более точнее скажут в ноябре. Если вы предполагаете распространять свои продукт как опенсорсный (GPLv3 или совместимой), то вы должны быть готовы использовать опенсорсную Kendo, то есть вместе со своими исходниками, предоставлять также исходники Kendo. <br>
GPLv3 подразумевать возможность продажи продукта, но продавать надо вместе с исходными кодами. <br>
Таким образом вы должны будете готовы выложить за Kendo 500 убитых енотов и так же использовать GPLv3, то есть продавая свой продукт предоставлять исходные коды.

Answer (score 1):

Если пишете для западной фирмы, то эти вопросы имеют смысл, если для нас, то плюньте.

Вообще, писать имеет смысл или для себя (собственного развития или просто хобби) или конкретные вещи для конкретных людей, решая их реальные проблемы. При подобном раскладе лицензионная чистота значения не имеет.